# include(password.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, php-5.3

i am a newbie in yii framework its been just 4 days i am stuck in this problem can someone help me below is my code..

this is view ...

```
<div class="form">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeEmailField($model , 'email') ?>

</div>  

<div class="row">
<?php  echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'password'); ?>
<?php  echo  CHtml::activePasswordField($model, 'password');  ?>

</div>
 <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

my simple code for model

```
<?php
class C_regsiter extends CFormModel{

public $username;
public $Password;
public $email;
public $data; 
protected  $id;

public function rules(){

return array(

array('username','password','email','required'),
array('email','email'),      

);

 }

public function attributelabel(){


 return array(

 'username'=>'User Name',
 'Password'=>'Password',
 'email'=>'Email Address '

); 

}

}
```

this is my controller

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
 public function actionIndex()
 {
  $model=new C_regsiter();
  $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));

 }
```

the problem is whenever is call the activepasswordfield is got an error please 
help

Comment: include(password.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about Yii 1 right?
Check your models rules definition. The "required" notation is wrong. It should be
`array('username, password, email', 'required'),`

First element should be the attributes, second the validator.
`array('attribute list', 'validator name', 'on'=>'scenario name', ...validation parameters...)`

See the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#rules-detail).

What your code tried to do: It takes the second element as a validator class, which it tries to include, but you don't have such a file, hence the include error.